# Programmatically disable category

Tags: magento

Is it possible to disable a category programmatically in magento ?
I have tried

```
Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category_id)->update($category_id,0);
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chinta .Please  the below.Magento disable a category using a field `is_active`

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load( $catId );
$cat->setData('is_active', 0);
$cat->save();
```